# What is the class name for Razor component without a code behind

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a razor component and I would like to add logging. What is the class name I should use?
Would I have to use code-behind when I need to do this?

Say that my component is called MyRazor.razor

```
@code {
[Inject]
public ILogger<MYCLASS> Logger { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### MyRazor.razor

```cs
@code {
  [Inject] public ILogger<MyRazor> Logger { get; set; }

}
```

Razor derives the classname from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach that doesn't require a separate logger to be injected for all components.

```
    services.AddScoped<ILogger, Logger<LoggingBroker>>();
    services.AddScoped<ILoggingBroker, LoggingBroker>();
```

```
 public class LoggingBroker : ILoggingBroker
 {
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public LoggingBroker(ILogger logger) => this.logger = logger;

    public void LogCritical(Exception exception) =>
        this.logger.LogCritical(exception, exception.Message);

    public void LogDebug(string message) => this.logger.LogDebug(message);

    public void LogError(Exception exception) =>
        this.logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
  
    public void LogInformation(string message) => this.logger.LogInformation(message);
    public void LogTrace(string message) => this.logger.LogTrace(message);
    public void LogWarning(string message) => this.logger.LogWarning(message);
}
```

Then inject your `ILoggingBroker`, I use this to allow unit testing.

```
@code {
    [Inject] 
    public ILoggingBroker Logger { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding:

> Would I have to use code-behind when I need to do this

No a `.razor` generates a class without the need for code-behind.

Note: I can provide the `ILoggingBroker` interface if needed but just extract it from the class provided.